# jruby/warbler: NoClassDefFound: Could not initialize org.jruby.ext.openssl.ASN1

Tags: ruby, jruby, redmine, warbler

I tried to use Warbler to make a war of a redmine installation.

I first installed JRuby (1.7.4), then download all gems with ''jruby -S gem install ...'', ''jruby -S bundle''.

I then installed warbler, and tried with or without specifying jruby-openssl in config.gems

> org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (LoadError) load error: openssl -- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.jruby.ext.openssl.ASN1

I also tried with JRuby 1.7.3 and JRuby 1.7.1, although the .war file that is generated is almost the same size.

I understand that jruby-openssl is part of jruby now.

How can I make this work?

**UPDATE:** it works with jruby, without making a war. So, I guess warbler must do the packaging wrong.